# Pager doesn't work in views block if views php field is used

Tags: 7, paging, views

I have a views block that shows nodes in some conditions. The views has pager and normally it works but if I use **Global: PHP** field the pager doesn't work and it only show the first page.

The Global: PHP field is as below:

- **Value Code**: *emtpy*
- **Output Code**:

->

```
<?php if ($row->type == 'book') { ?>
        <i class="fa fa-book fa-lg fa-fw"></i>
<?php }
elseif ($row->type == 'article') {
?>
        <i class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-lg fa-fw"></i>
<?php }
elseif ($row->type == 'thesis') {
?>
        <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap fa-lg fa-fw"></i>
<?php } ?>
```

---

#### UPDATE:

I'm listing the nodes in this views block. There are 3 different content types and what I want to do with this PHP field is to print an icon according to content type. The code checks the content type with `if ($row->type == ...)`.

*(End of update.)*

---

**The PHP field works correctly and gives what I want but I wonder if I do something wrong in the PHP structure.**

Do you have any idea what can cause this problem?

Comment: hello and welcome. Please remember that bug reports are not allowed here. I'm afraid your question looks like one now. Of this is a problem with your code in that field, phrase state it more clearly.

Comment: @Mołot hello and thanks. I think it's not a bug report; the PHP code I used maybe caused the problem. I'm editing the question and adding details.

Comment: The real issue for this is here https://www.drupal.org/node/2123315

Comment: @rooby, thanks and sorry for the late replay. Yes, as you said it seems a 'bug' and there are some solutions. And also, did you remove your answer?

Comment: Yep I deleted my answer because I realized it contained misinformation. The code in your question should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a patch for that: [Pager disappears when Global: PHP used in Views 3.8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2276165)

> After upgrading from Views version 7.x-3.7 to 7.x-3.8, the pager was
>   missing from all views that used Global: PHP fields.

If patch#6 does not work for you, just follow the links in comment#27

Comment: That issue has been marked a duplicate of https://www.drupal.org/node/2123315 which apparently has a proper fix.

Comment: Thanks, patch#6 worked correctly and solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

For one thing I know Drupal does not like ending php tags '`?>`' at the end of pages and no start or ending tags in most PHP fields I have seen. If that is not the issue can you put up an image of the field from the edit screen it might help to better understand what you mean?

Comment: In the output code description, it says that: __Code to construct the output of this field. Use <?php ?> delimiters to enclose PHP code.__

Comment: It does indeed say that. The other PHP code I have entered into views has told me the opposite. I will take a deeper look.

Comment: It varies depending on the developer who created the module's preference.