# Pager missing in View

Tags: views, paging

I have a view with navigation set to paged, 12 items. I can see 12 items (there are way more available), but no pager. Googling this problem I found the following solutions that didn't work:

View uses Global: PHP fields (my view doesn't do that)

View is displayed in a block (my view is displayed in a page)

Changing pager id (tried everything from 0 to 5, also, this is the only pager on this page)

It's also not a styling issue, the pager is not in the markup. I didn't override any templates related to the view.

In other views, the pager works and I can also see it in the views preview. In this view, I can't even see it in the preview - this should prove that it's not a theming issue as well, am I right?

I tried displaying a "more" link, but that didn't work as well. Changing the navigation to "mini pager" also doesn't help.

The view is using a relationship to an entity reference, but that shouldn't be an issue IMO. Other than that it's a pretty ordinary view displaying some fields. Anyone have any ideas?

(Drupal 7, Views 3)

Comment: Do you have any pager plugins enabled? And is the view set to be cached?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pager doesn't work in views block if views php field is used](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/140559/pager-doesnt-work-in-views-block-if-views-php-field-is-used)

Comment: Drupalist: No, not a duplicate, as I said in the question, I'm not using such a field and don't even have this module installed

Comment: Clive: No, don't have any pager plugins or caching for this view enabled.

Comment: Same or simillar Issue i have in D8 :/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an old bug that been fixed, so it is no longer on topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, the View was set to display as a Display Suite Layout and the pager field was hidden in the settings of the Layout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have caching enabled for this view.  You can disable caching for this view or, better, you can apply this patch: https://www.drupal.org/node/1819538

Comment: No, caching is disabled for this view.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in `Views Php` module,there is a patch for that: [Pager disappears when Global: PHP used in Views 3.8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2276165)

> After upgrading from Views version 7.x-3.7 to 7.x-3.8, the pager was
>   missing from all views that used Global: PHP fields.

I had the same problem and [#6](https://www.drupal.org/node/2276165#comment-8835945) worked for me ,If patch#6 does not work for you, just follow the links in [#27](https://www.drupal.org/node/2276165#comment-8970447)

Comment: Question states "View uses Global: PHP fields (my view doesn't do that)". I'm not using the Views PHP Module.

Comment: @1nterference It is not important you use or not use Php fields, try it please